# Function for ingesting dataset and spilting into smaller datasets with individual names?

Tags: python, dataframe, chunks

I have a large dataset I would like to spilt into chunks of 10,000 rows or so and give a name to each dataset.
Right now I am doing it manually but I know there is a better way.

```
df1 = df[0:10000]
df2 = df[10001:20000]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# some big DataFrame
# df = ...

# size of chunks
step = 10_000
chunks = [df[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(df), step)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Arica

Where is the data coming from?

If it's a file, e.g. a CSV, you could read it 10000 rows at a time.

The following code will create a dictionary with keys DataFrame0, DataFrame1 etc.

The value for each key will be a dataframe with 10,000 rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data_iterator = pd.read_csv('bigcsv.csv', chunksize=10000, header=None)

for d in data_iterator:
    print(d)
```